# Need not to print Duplicates values using c#

Tags: c#

this is the code where i am printing "m_USTByDoctor_OPDC.ml_trn_bill_item " the value come from database.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_USTByDoctor_OPDC.ml_trn_bill_item.Count;i++ )
   {

   int count = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j m_USTByDoctor_OPDC.ml_trn_bill_item.Count; j++)
                {
if(m_USTByDoctor_OPDC.ml_trn_bill_item[j].ItemName==m_USTByDoctor_OPDC.ml_trn_bill_item[i].ItemName)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }

                Add_Cell(m_USTByDoctor_OPDC.ml_trn_bill_item[i].ItemName, ref tbl_summaryContent3, HELVETICA_BOLD_8_BLACK, false, Rectangle.ALIGN_LEFT, Rectangle.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                Add_Cell(count.ToString(), ref tbl_summaryContent3, HELVETICA_NORMAL_8_BLACK, false, Rectangle.ALIGN_LEFT, Rectangle.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            }
```

This is the out put i am geting as you there Repated values also i need to eliminate it how can i do it

```
   Abdomen & Pelvic Scan IP   3
    Abdomen & Pelvic Scan IP   3
    Abdomine Pelvic Scan - OP   5
    Abdomine Pelvic Scan - OP   5
    Anamoly Scan (Single) - OP  1
    Abdomine Pelvic Scan - OP  5
    Abdomine Pelvic Scan - OP  5
    Abdomine Pelvic Scan - OP  5
    ANC/Obstetrics Scan(OP)    1
    Abdomen & Pelvic Scan IP  3
```

Comment: Why Java and asp.net if you are coding with C#?

Comment: `.Distinct()` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `GroupBy` linq extension method:

```
foreach (var group in m_USTByDoctor_OPDC.ml_trn_bill_item.GroupBy(i => i.ItemName))
{
    Add_Cell(group.Key, ref tbl_summaryContent3, HELVETICA_BOLD_8_BLACK, false, Rectangle.ALIGN_LEFT, Rectangle.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    Add_Cell(group.Count().ToString(), ref tbl_summaryContent3, HELVETICA_NORMAL_8_BLACK, false, Rectangle.ALIGN_LEFT, Rectangle.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error as  Error 6 A local variable named 'i' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'i', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: Since this code should replace both your loops, the `i` should be available - but you can choose another identifier for the lambda if you want.

Comment: thank you C Evenhuis... problem solved